# How to backup a large multi-partition hard-disk towards a small one?

Tags: backup, boot-loader, restore, partition-table

In order to help someone else to learn to get used to Linux -- and get out of the Windows version downward spiral --, I need to install Debian Linux GNOME exclusively on a Laptop. However, for the backup plan, and eventually wanting to sell the machine some day, I need a backup of the actual system partitions. Since the Samsung Laptop has a plethora of hidden-service-security-etc.-&-blablabla partitions (seven) on a 500GB disk there are some challenges for the data backup.

1. Possibility to restore the actual state (partition tables + boot-loader + Windows 8.1 with actual installs & settings + all service partitions) *fast & reliably* -- preferably in one step without any complications.
2. Backup all at once.
3. It would be really nice if I could make a smaller (>>500GB) image then the hard-drive -- since the space now in use on all partitions is totaling about 125GB.
4. If it's possible, it would be nice to be able to explore the "image" of the multiple partitions. [Macrium Reflect (on Windows)](https://askleo.com/macrium_reflect_powerful_windows_backup_software/) offers this feature, however, in it's proprietary format -- would rather prefer an open/free format.

(After researching a bit for a good solutions, asked me how it would be if I minimize the size of the Windows partition -- let's say 80GB -- and let the space remaining unallocated. So the total size of the allocated partitions would be about 125GB. Then cloning _all_the_allocated_partitions_ with something like *Clonezilla* or *dd*. Would be nice if it's possible to use an Live Debian 8 (Jessie) for the operation -- thanks to Ben Armstrong, I already managed to get a [persistent system on an USB-key](http://syn.theti.ca/2013/06/22/tutorial-wheezy-live-iso-hybrid-with-persistence-on-usb/) --, but I'm *open to any reliable solution*. Could this work?

Update: After downsizing the Windows partition and getting the proposed unallocated space I realized that, partially, there are service partitions at the end of the hard-drive. So the unallocated space is in between the allocated-space/partitions -- could this be an issue?)

Answer (score 1):

A trick I like to use for this sort of thing is **sparse copying**.  Try the following:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=some_file bs=1024 count=1 seek=1048576
$ ls -l some_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 jander jander 1073742848 Nov 20 23:38 foo
$ du some_file
12      some_file
```

The file size is 1GB, but the disk space used is 12kB.  Now, if you `cat` this file, you'll get 1GB worth of zeroes.  Crazy, right?  The trick is that we're only writing the last 1kB of the file, so Linux just records that there's only 1kB of actual data and it's at an offset of 1GB into the file.  Anywhere there's not actual data will read back as zeroes.

#### Sparse-cloning an arbitrary disk: the universal, dumb way

So to make use of this to back up a filesystem, you can fill all unused space on the filesystem with zeroes, then use `dd` with the `conv=sparse` option to create a sparse image.  To make things easier, we'll clone the entire disk at once.

```
$ mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/fill_up_with_zeroes bs=1048576
$ rm /mnt/fill_up_with_zeroes
$ umount /mnt
$ mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/fill_up_with_zeroes bs=1048576
$ rm /mnt/fill_up_with_zeroes
$ umount /dev/sdc2 /mnt
$ dd if=/dev/sdc of=sdc-sparse.img bs=1048576 conv=sparse
```

Then, to restore:

```
$ dd if=sdc-sparse.img of=/dev/sdc bs=1048576
```

Beware that when writing your image back to a real hard drive, you should *not* make a sparse copy.  If you do, you'll end up corrupting the filesystem: any place that contained a block of zeroes would instead contain a block of random data in its place!

Finally, if the laptop is new and you haven't deleted any files from it, don't bother zeroing out the unused space on the partitions -- they're probably already zeroed.

#### Sparse-cloning an NTFS partition: there's a tool for that

Now, if you're working specifically with NTFS filesystems, there's a tool for that: `ntfsclone`.  It creates a sparse copy of an NTFS filesystem.  It will do a better job than `dd` and it will do it faster, because it knows what parts of the NTFS filesystem are safe to ignore.

However, you'll have to keep each partition in a separate file in that case.  You'll also have to back up your partition table separately -- using `dd bs=512 count=63` should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. ASAP (this weekend) I will happily test your proposal. Is it possible to offer an restore command for the first (prefered) solution. Have a nice day and thank you.

Comment: I've tried your proposal, and had some difficulties figuring out how to recover the backed-up data. Considering the first point (1.) above, I've searched for a consequent solution and tested [this Clonezilla variant](http://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image/06-dev-img.doc#06-dev-img.doc). Clonezilla achieved to minimize the backup size to 68.2GB (7 partititions, 500GB HDD), in one step. Since I prefer this solution I will rate your answer as preferred, only if you include the Clonzilla variant to your answer. In any case, thank you very much.

Comment: It might be more helpful for the community if you wrote up your experience with Clonezilla as a separate answer.  Then you can accept your own answer, since that was what solved your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do it, and a good week-start.